# Conditionally multiply values in a dataframe by another dataframe if above a certain threshold in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to multiply corresponding rows of dataframe 1, column 'Pdist', by dataframe 2, column 'Pdist', if the value in dataframe 1 is above the 'threshold'. If it isn't above the threshold, the value must remain unchanged instead.

Below is some example data:

```
dataframe_1 <- data.frame(ind_comp_a = c("OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2413iiiaMOU","OP5046___eWAT","OP2413iiicMOU","OP2413iiibMOU","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___eWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5046___dWAT","OP5046___eWAT","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___ePHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5048___ePHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5044___cMOU","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5046___aWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___bWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5048___dPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2413iiibMOU","OP2413iiicMOU","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5044___cMOU","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2413iiiaMOU","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___dWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5046___dWAT","OP2413iiibMOU","OP2413iiicMOU","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5049___bWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP2413iiiaMOU","OP5046___cWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5043___aWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___eWAT","OP5048___hPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5048___hPHA","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5048___cPHA","OP5046___cWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___cWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5043___bWAT","OP5046___dWAT","OP5048___hPHA","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5048___dPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5044___cMOU","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP5044___cMOU","OP2645ii_ePOR"),
                          ind_comp_b = c("OP5048___bPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5046___bWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5043___bWAT","OP5043___aWAT","OP5047___bPHA","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5049___aWAT","OP5046___cWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP5044___aMOU","OP5051DNAaCOM","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___gPHA","OP5054DNAbMOU","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5051DNAcCOM","OP5048___fPHA","OP5046___aWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP5049___bWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5044___bMOU","OP3088i__aPOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5048___ePHA","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___ePHA","OP5043___aWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5043___bWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5044___cMOU","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5047___bPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5049___bWAT","OP5049___bWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5043___aWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5047___aPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___dPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5043___aWAT","OP5043___bWAT","OP5043___bWAT","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5049___bWAT","OP5047___aPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5047___bPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5047___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___dPHA","OP5048___gPHA","OP5049___aWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5046___cWAT","OP5048___dPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5047___aPHA","OP5048___dPHA","OP5049___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___gPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___bPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5051DNAaCOM","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5044___aMOU","OP5051DNAcCOM","OP5049___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5047___aPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5051DNAcCOM","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5049___aWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5054DNAbMOU","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5043___bWAT","OP5043___aWAT","OP5049___aWAT","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5049___aWAT"),
                          Pdist = c(0.12653736,0.12545262,0.12409420,0.12023167,0.11852507,0.11574044,0.11371805,0.11165877,0.11096499,0.11000436,0.10860921,0.10716355,0.10648404,0.10457088,0.10043985,0.10043419,0.09902992,0.09809625,0.09742466,0.09706079,0.09691789,0.09532336,0.09374877,0.09359057,0.09352572,0.09191749,0.09136457,0.08965083,0.08872891,0.08630526,0.08531594,0.08454861,0.08453494,0.08312192,0.08258318,0.08140542,0.08140466,0.08083571,0.08036883,0.07964833,0.07964736,0.07930556,0.07916955,0.07909909,0.07871759,0.07749702,0.07735318,0.07692221,0.07663146,0.07655228,0.07610728,0.07601355,0.07589804,0.07586683,0.07475816,0.07427158,0.07295387,0.07264578,0.07239881,0.07239652,0.07230148,0.07213147,0.07178486,0.07143912,0.07102923,0.07034595,0.07017927,0.07009262,0.06990277,0.06953688,0.06945218,0.06933059,0.06923690,0.06918330,0.06905105,0.06894675,0.06886782,0.06873706,0.06835633,0.06827398,0.06818929,0.06815169,0.06781528,0.06755839,0.06709807,0.06673160,0.06651507,0.06631521,0.06577319,0.06527915,0.06521944,0.06479374,0.06450183,0.06444880,0.06439217,0.06363232,0.06313289,0.06312447,0.06301823,0.06299480,0.06277461,0.06277369,0.06274871,0.06205441,0.06190890,0.06190525,0.06183778,0.06180255,0.06174675,0.06142775,0.06142015,0.06141977,0.06132026,0.06126746,0.06121289,0.06106807,0.06069853,0.06060409,0.06057873,0.06002828,0.05988876,0.05983741,0.05952482,0.05916929,0.05912005,0.05911979,0.05906816,0.05899453,0.05865145,0.05853252,0.05818659,0.05785562,0.05784148,0.05781387,0.05760903,0.05755058,0.05742954,0.05731918,0.05701451,0.05701384,0.05698890,0.05686745,0.05665475,0.05662290,0.05661457,0.05648999,0.05641717,0.05638154,0.05633743,0.05630275,0.05624860,0.05594854,0.05594397,0.05581496,0.05577077,0.05576073,0.05571763,0.05552730,0.05545187,0.05541380,0.05508725,0.05495578,0.05481013,0.05478274,0.05476202,0.05470291,0.05452429,0.05403781,0.05369966,0.05355532,0.05337705,0.05334701,0.05318317,0.05289062,0.05281420))
dataframe_2 <- data.frame(ind_comp_a = c("OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2413iiiaMOU","OP5046___eWAT","OP2413iiicMOU","OP2413iiibMOU","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___eWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5046___dWAT","OP5046___eWAT","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___ePHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5048___ePHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5044___cMOU","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5046___aWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5046___bWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5048___dPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2413iiibMOU","OP2413iiicMOU","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5044___cMOU","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2413iiiaMOU","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___dWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5046___dWAT","OP2413iiibMOU","OP2413iiicMOU","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5049___bWAT","OP5046___aWAT","OP2413iiiaMOU","OP5046___cWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5043___aWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___eWAT","OP5048___hPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5048___hPHA","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5048___cPHA","OP5046___cWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5046___cWAT","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5043___bWAT","OP5046___dWAT","OP5048___hPHA","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5048___dPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_aPOR","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5044___cMOU","OP5046___eWAT","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP2645ii_bPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP5044___cMOU","OP2645ii_ePOR"),
                          ind_comp_b = c("OP5048___bPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5046___bWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5043___bWAT","OP5043___aWAT","OP5047___bPHA","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5049___aWAT","OP5046___cWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5046___eWAT","OP5044___aMOU","OP5051DNAaCOM","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___gPHA","OP5054DNAbMOU","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5051DNAcCOM","OP5048___fPHA","OP5046___aWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP5049___bWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5044___bMOU","OP3088i__aPOR","OP5046___dWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5048___ePHA","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5048___fPHA","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___ePHA","OP5043___aWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5043___bWAT","OP5048___fPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5044___cMOU","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5047___bPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5049___bWAT","OP5049___bWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5043___aWAT","OP5046___bWAT","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5047___aPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___dPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5043___aWAT","OP5043___bWAT","OP5043___bWAT","OP2645ii_cPOR","OP5049___bWAT","OP5047___aPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5048___bPHA","OP2645ii_ePOR","OP5047___bPHA","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5047___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___dPHA","OP5048___gPHA","OP5049___aWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5053DNAcPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5048___hPHA","OP5046___cWAT","OP5048___dPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5048___cPHA","OP5048___bPHA","OP5047___aPHA","OP5046___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5047___aPHA","OP5048___dPHA","OP5049___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___gPHA","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5048___bPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___ePHA","OP5051DNAaCOM","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5044___aMOU","OP5051DNAcCOM","OP5049___bWAT","OP5054DNAaMOU","OP5047___aPHA","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP2645ii_dPOR","OP5051DNAcCOM","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5049___aWAT","OP5053DNAaPHA","OP5048___fPHA","OP5054DNAcMOU","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5054DNAbMOU","OP5052DNAaWAT","OP5048___ePHA","OP5053DNAbPHA","OP5043___bWAT","OP5043___aWAT","OP5049___aWAT","OP5051DNAbCOM","OP5049___aWAT"),
                          Pdist = c(12.653736,12.545262,12.40942,12.023167,11.852507,11.574044,11.371805,11.165877,11.096499,11.000436,10.860921,10.716355,10.648404,10.457088,10.043985,10.043419,9.902992,9.809625,9.742466,9.706079,9.691789,9.532336,9.374877,9.359057,9.352572,9.191749,9.136457,8.965083,8.872891,8.630526,8.531594,8.454861,8.453494,8.312192,8.258318,8.140542,8.140466,8.083571,8.036883,7.964833,7.964736,7.930556,7.916955,7.909909,7.871759,7.749702,7.735318,7.692221,7.663146,7.655228,7.610728,7.601355,7.589804,7.586683,7.475816,7.427158,7.295387,7.264578,7.239881,7.239652,7.230148,7.213147,7.178486,7.143912,7.102923,7.034595,7.017927,7.009262,6.990277,6.953688,6.945218,6.933059,6.92369,6.91833,6.905105,6.894675,6.886782,6.873706,6.835633,6.827398,6.818929,6.815169,6.781528,6.755839,6.709807,6.67316,6.651507,6.631521,6.577319,6.527915,6.521944,6.479374,6.450183,6.44488,6.439217,6.363232,6.313289,6.312447,6.301823,6.29948,6.277461,6.277369,6.274871,6.205441,6.19089,6.190525,6.183778,6.180255,6.174675,6.142775,6.142015,6.141977,6.132026,6.126746,6.121289,6.106807,6.069853,6.060409,6.057873,6.002828,5.988876,5.983741,5.952482,5.916929,5.912005,5.911979,5.906816,5.899453,5.865145,5.853252,5.818659,5.785562,5.784148,5.781387,5.760903,5.755058,5.742954,5.731918,5.701451,5.701384,5.69889,5.686745,5.665475,5.66229,5.661457,5.648999,5.641717,5.638154,5.633743,5.630275,5.62486,5.594854,5.594397,5.581496,5.577077,5.576073,5.571763,5.55273,5.545187,5.54138,5.508725,5.495578,5.481013,5.478274,5.476202,5.470291,5.452429,5.403781,5.369966,5.355532,5.337705,5.334701,5.318317,5.289062,5.28142))

threshold <- 0.08
```

Thanks! Cheers! Deon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the indices where `Pdist` is greater than `threshold` and then multiply.

```
inds <- dataframe_1$Pdist > threshold
dataframe_1$Pdist[inds] <- dataframe_1$Pdist[inds] * dataframe_2$Pdist[inds]
```